# Pancake sort algorithm implementation (18/11n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

So I have been researching the pancake sort. In the [Wikipedia article for pancake sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting#The_original_pancake_problem) it says that

> The simplest pancake sorting algorithm requires at most 2n − 3 flips...
>   In 1979, Bill Gates and Christos Papadimitriou[3] gave an upper
>   bound of 5/3n. This was improved, thirty years later, to 18/11n by a
>   team of researchers at the University of Texas at Dallas, led by
>   Founders Professor Hal Sudborough[4] (Chitturi et al., 2009).

I looked at the University of Texas paper myself but couldn't really understand it so I thought maybe I could find an implementation of the algorithm. But if I search for implementations I can not find anything else but versions of the simple algorithm requiring 2n - 3 flips.

Why is that? Is the more efficient algorithm so complex that people just don't bother with it or haven't I just searched hard enough for implementations or am I missing something else here?

Comment: A search for "pancake sort implementation" returned this for the first result: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pancake-sorting/. Also, http://austingwalters.com/everyday-algorithms-pancake-sort/ has a decent discussion of the naive algorithm.

Comment: For those who are interested, you can get the UT paper at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397508003575. The Gates paper is at http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~christos/papers/Bounds%20For%20Sorting%20By%20Prefix%20Reversal.pdf

Comment: @Jim Mischel yes but those implementations are for the simple algorithm, right? Im looking for the 18/11n one

Comment: By the way, sorting by reversal isn't used for general sorting because reversal is expensive.